# $('textarea').rows expand/contract

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, textarea, rows

I am new to jQuery/Javascript and even newer to scouring over minified jQuery/Javascript.

I am trying to recreate some functionality I found in the form component of the Materialize Framework. If you visit the following link:

http://materializecss.com/forms.html

You'll see their  example `<textarea>` element expands/contracts depending on how many rows are in the element.  (this is my assumption as to how it's working anyway; as my knowledge of jQuery is lacking I'm unsure exactly how it's being done. I can't find what I'm looking for in the minified script).

I don't believe it's being done with pure css and so this is why I have been looking through the .js.

I have attempted to recreate the functionality with my limited knowledge, but my code leaves much to be desired.

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
  if($(this).rows == +1) {
    console.log('+1 row');
    $(this).animate({'height': '+=16'}, 250);
  } else if (this.rows == -1) {
    console.log('-1 row');
    $(this).animate({'height': '-=16'}, 250);
  }
});
```

If anyone is able to either correct my script or identify exactly what is happening with the Materialize Framework so that I may recreate this without leaning on the framework itself, I would be eternally grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$(this).rows` ==> `$(this).attr('rows')`, I hope this will solved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may help

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
      $(this).css({'height': 'auto'});
      $(this).height( this.scrollHeight );
});
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ewf491wg/1/)

Comment: Thanks for this; This is close to a working solution. Not entirely like the example I posted though.

Comment: Also add `textarea { overflow:hidden; }` not to be showing the scrollbar for a second.

Comment: I've made a jsfiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/jjz3rqpo/
This is almost exactly what I want. How would I now animate the transition? It seems that css transitions aren't being picked up because the css height value we are feeding the element is inline in the markup. also replacing .css() with .animate() causes textarea to expand every single time a key is pressed, so that's not going to work either.

Comment: @DanMad I tried a lot of times working around that but I really cant get an effect you want ..  maybe  it needs a lot of time again .. you can use this code right now till you reach the effect you need .. Good Luck .. http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ewf491wg/1/

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef thank you for your solution. I will tick that this answers my question; it's a minimum viable product kind of solution, but it will keep my momentum ;)